# Using SQL UNION with Codeigniter/PHP in an autocomplete search query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, union, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to develop an autocomplete function in Codeigniter, can someone let me know if there is any problem with this query? It seems reasonable to me, but I'm not getting any output...

for example, if someone types in 'Ma' in the search box, i want to use the following query..

```
$term=$this->input->post('term')='Ma'; 

$this->db->query(  'SELECT subject
                    FROM items
                    WHERE subject LIKE 'Ma%'
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT first_name
                    FROM accounts
                    WHERE first_name LIKE 'Ma%'
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT description
                    FROM items
                    WHERE description LIKE 'Ma%'');
$query=$this->db->get();

$items = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
array_push($items, $row->subject);

$companies = array_slice($items, 0, 5);
echo json_encode($items);
```

The result should look something like this:

```
Marios Shoes1
Mario Shoes9
marklast
Mark
marktwook
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this is using ajax - use firebug w/ firefox or something similar with google chrome to debug the requests. Using firebug, you could view the request to see if it was successful or not, and usually in the response portion it'll show you any errors codeigniter outputted.

Comment: Unless it's a typo, the line `$term=$this->input->post('term')='Ma';` returns a `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in [..]`, for me at least.

Comment: Also do a `print_r($query->result());` and see if you get the data you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using query then I think it should be done like this

```
$query = $this->db->query(  'SELECT subject
                    FROM items
                    WHERE subject LIKE 'Ma%'
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT first_name
                    FROM accounts
                    WHERE first_name LIKE 'Ma%'
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT description
                    FROM items
                    WHERE description LIKE 'Ma%'');
```